# In Psynet I am unable to do dallinger generate constraint

Tags: python

`dallinger generate-constraints` fails. Error includes:

```
pip._internal.exceptions.NetworkConnectionError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dallinger/Dallinger/v7.9.0a1/dev-requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be potentially a bug in the master branch of dallinger. This is solved by reverting to tagged version (e.g `git checkout tags/v5.1.0`) and reinstalling this version (e.g `pip3 install -e .`).